# boost property tree put/get DBL_MAX

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm programming a ptree and at some point I need to put DBL_MAX in (as a default value).
I see the right number when I open the generated xml-file.

But when I use ptree.get to get the number an exception is thrown:`conversion of data to type "d" failed`

Here's my code:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;

double d=-DBL_MAX;
double d2=-1.797693134862316e+308;
double d3=-1.79769e+308;

cout<<d<<endl;
cout<<d2<<endl;
cout<<d3<<endl;

pt.put<double>("double", d);
write_xml("test.xml", pt);

cout << "totalEndTimeLowerBound: " << pt.get<double>("double")<<endl;
//doesn't work with d and d2, but works with d3
```

What can cause this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

By default, `ptree` stores its values as `std::string` and convert them using `basic_stringstream` with precision:

```
s.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10+1);
```

This problem appears when it converts `DBL_MAX` to `std::string` because it rounds the number to an invalid value. You can check it with the following code:

```
ptree pt;
pt.put("min", -DBL_MAX);
pt.put("max", DBL_MAX);
cout << "Min=" << pt.get<string>("min") << std::endl;
cout << "Max=" << pt.get<string>("max") << std::endl;
```

Using Visual Studio, it prints:

> Min=-1.797693134862316e+308
>
> Max= 1.797693134862316e+308

However, `DBL_MAX` is defined as `1.7976931348623158e+308` so the printed value is out of limits.

There are several workarounds but none is perfect:

- Use a different default value smaller than `DBL_MAX`. For example `1.797693134862315e+308`.
- Catch the `bad_data` exception and assume that it means default.
- Register a new type with your custom converter. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105184/218774).
- Reduce the precision of the stored value. You can perform this using the following code:

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace property_tree 
  {
    template <typename Ch, typename Traits>
    struct customize_stream<Ch, Traits, double, void>
    {
      static void insert(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Traits>& s, const double& e) {
        s.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10-1);
        s << e;
      }
      static void extract(std::basic_istream<Ch, Traits>& s, double& e) {
        s >> e;
        if(!s.eof()) {
          s >> std::ws;
         }
      }
    };
  }
  ```