# how to create xml using boost property_tree

Tags: c++, boost, xml-parsing

i need to create xml for my output.
I have a list of index names.
i want to populate it in an xml file in one format.

that is

```
<response>
      <indexes>
          <index>abc</index>
          <index>xyz</index>
          <index>pqr</index>
      </indexes>
</response>
```

I have the list in my vector index_list.

Can any one help me out.

I have tried some code for that.
which follows

```
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
stringstream output;
for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator it = index_list.begin();
        it != index_list.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
    tree.put("response.indexes.index", *it);
}
if (format == "xml") {
    write_xml(output, tree);
} else {
    write_json(output, tree);
}
```

When i run the above code . i m getting only last name in the list. that is

```
<response>
  <indexes>
      <index>pqr</index>
  </indexes>
</response>
```

Comment: [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2bMAyG$0) works. I don't have any experience with this library so I don't know if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: thanks llonesmiz.. Your way of doing is also good.. impressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` method will erase any existing value, see the earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072704/boost-property-tree-multiple-values-per-key) that's related.

You'll have to use different keys for each entry in the list for your logic to avoid data loss.

[Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html) say

> Calling put will insert a new value at specified path, so that a call
>   to get specifying the same path will retrieve it.

Comment: thanks for your info. if i use put i cant get xml like <indexes><index/><index/></indexes>.. i will try add()..

Comment: My impression is that this is a feature of propertytree.  XML is just used to represent the data structure, so don't expect to do everything with PTree that you can do in XML.