# Adding nodes with the same key to a property tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I am using Boost's property tree to read and write XML. Using a spreadsheet application I made I want to save the contents of the spreadsheet to xml. This is a school assignment so I am required to use the following format for the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spreadsheet>
   <cell>
      <name>A2</name>
      <contents>adsf</contents>
   </cell>
   <cell>
      <name>D6</name>
      <contents>345</contents>
   </cell>
   <cell>
      <name>D2</name>
      <contents>=d6</contents>  
   </cell>
</spreadsheet>
```

For a simple test program I wrote:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

pt.put("spreadsheet.cell.name", "a2");
pt.put("spreadsheet.cell.contents", "adsf");

write_xml("output.xml", pt);

boost::property_tree::ptree ptr;
read_xml("output.xml", ptr);

ptr.put("spreadsheet.cell.name", "d6");
ptr.put("spreadsheet.cell.contents", "345");
ptr.put("spreadsheet.cell.name", "d2");
ptr.put("spreadsheet.cell.contents", "=d6");

write_xml("output2.xml", ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413022/how-to-create-xml-using-boost-property-tree) I see the `put` method replaces anything at that node, instead of adding a new one. Which is exactly the functionality I am seeing:

**Output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<spreadsheet>
  <cell>
    <name>a2</name>
    <contents>adsf</contents>
  </cell>
</spreadsheet>
```

**Output2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<spreadsheet>
  <cell>
    <name>d2</name>
    <contents>=d6</contents>
  </cell>
</spreadsheet>
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id906314-bb) I see this `add_child` method which will `Add the node at the given path. Create any missing parents. If there already is a node at the path, add another one with the same key.`

I can't quite figure out how to use that `add_child` method, could someone explain how to use it?

Is there a better way of going about this to achieve the file format I want?

Comment: Can't you just use the cell name in the child name? i.e. `"spreadsheet.cell.d6"`

Comment: @k-ballo because that wouldn't meet the xml requirements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `add_child` member function allows you to insert one `property_tree` into the DOM of another as a child node. If the key path you provide already exists a duplicate key will be added and the child will be inserted there instead. If we change your example a little bit we can examine the results.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Create the first tree with two elements, name and contents
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptr1;
    ptr1.put("name", "a2");
    ptr1.put("contents", "adsf");

    // Create the a second tree with two elements, name and contents
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptr2;
    ptr2.put("name", "d6");
    ptr2.put("contents", "345");

    // Add both trees to a third and place them in node "spreadsheet.cell"
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptr3;
    ptr3.add_child("spreadsheet.cell", ptr1);
    ptr3.add_child("spreadsheet.cell", ptr2);

    boost::property_tree::write_xml("output.xml", ptr3);

    return 0;
}
```

When you call `add_child` the first time, the node for key "spreadsheet.cell" does not exist and is created. It then adds the contents of the tree (`name` and `contents`) to the newly created node. When you call `add_child` the second time it sees that "spreadsheet.cell" already exists but unlike `put` it creates a sibling node also called "cell" and inserts it at the same location.

The final output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<spreadsheet>
  <cell>
    <name>a2</name>
    <contents>adsf</contents>
  </cell>
  <cell>
    <name>d6</name>
    <contents>345</contents>
  </cell>
</spreadsheet>
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. If I were to want to update cell `d6` however, how would i navigate to that cell and change the contents in `ptr3`?

Comment: @Deekor Iterate over the children of `spreadsheet` looking for all children of type `cell`. Anytime you encounter one get the contents of `name` and if you find a match delete it. You'll need to look at the docs for specifics

Comment: nice explanation, not much documentation around add_child on net otherwise .

Comment: There is also `.add(name, value)`.