# Boost property_tree: multiple values per key, on a template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-propertytree

On this topic, [Boost property_tree: multiple values per key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072704/boost-property-tree-multiple-values-per-key), a method is proposed to read multiples keys of a boost tree. I will paste a modified version below

```
template<int dim>
struct my_vector
{
  std::vector<double> a_vector;
};
```

The translator would be:

```
template<int dim>
struct my_vector_translator
{
  typedef std::string    internal_type;
  typedef my_vector external_type;
  // Get a my_vector from a string
  boost::optional<external_type> get_value(const internal_type& str)
  {
    if (!str.empty())
    {
      std::vector val;
      val.resize(dim)
      std::stringstream s(str);
      double temp;
      for (int i=0, i < dim; ++i){
          s >> temp;
          val.a_vector[i] = temp;
      return boost::optional<external_type>(val);
    }
    else
      return boost::optional<external_type>(boost::none);
  }

};
```

And now, how should i do to register the translator properly ?

```
namespace boost { namespace property_tree 
{
  template<typename Ch, typename Traits, typename Alloc> 
  struct translator_between<std::basic_string< Ch, Traits, Alloc >, my_vector<it want something here of course, where do i get it from ?> >
  {
    typedef my_vector_translator<it want something here of course, where do i get it from ?> type;
  };
} }
```

After you include the previous code, you can use property_tree as:

```
  pt.get<my_vector ??and here where do i put the size ?>("box.x");
```

And somehow i feel that the class my_vector is useless. Couldn't I work directly with std::vector ?

I would like something like:

```
pt.get<std::vector<double>, 3>("mesh.a_line_where_i_know_i_have_3_doubles_to_read");
```

Thank you.

Comment: without a SSCCE this is not going anywhere

Comment: well, the SSCCE is contained in the answer given by J. Calleja in the other topic. My question is simply how one can extend it if low_high_value is a class that accepts template. I can copy paste their example if you deem it necessary.

Comment: Yes. By all means, tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: ok I inserted a more detailed example. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could use vecetor for the torage, but you'd still require the meta-data (size) to be available. So it doesn't change much

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that size is already the template argument to the `my_vector` class template.

So

```
pt.get<my_vector<3> >("box.x");
```

should be good

#### Registering:

A partial specialization can introduce extra template arguments, so just add `size_t N` to the list:

```
namespace boost { namespace property_tree {
    template<typename Ch, typename Traits, typename Alloc, size_t N> 
        struct translator_between<std::basic_string<Ch, Traits, Alloc>, my_vector<N> >
        {
            typedef my_vector_translator<N> type;
        };
} }
```